# Creating a matrix from Pandas dataframe to display connectedness

Tags: python, matrix

I have my data in this format in a pandas dataframe:

```
Customer_ID  Location_ID
Alpha             A
Alpha             B
Alpha             C
Beta              A
Beta              B
Beta              D
```

I want to study the mobility patterns of the customers. My goal is to determine the clusters of locations that are most frequented by customers. I think the following matrix can provide such information:

```
   A  B  C  D
A  0  2  1  1
B  2  0  1  1
C  1  1  0  0
D  1  1  0  0
```

How do I do so in Python?

My dataset is quite large (hundreds of thousands of customers and about a hundred locations).

Comment: Can you explain your expected output and/or input? An adjacency matrix doesn't seem to make sense based on what you've provided.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not seeing how you're defining this graph. Why are the edges between locations, rather than between customers and locations? Why does location B have a weight-2 edge to A when location C doesn't?

Comment: I think I made  a mistake in the previous matrix. I have corrected it now. Hope it makes more sense.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand what you're trying to do. For each customer, you're essentially creating a connected graph. What you're asking for is a sum of the adjacency matrices that represent these graphs. What's not clear is how 'A', 'B', and 'C' are connected. For example, customer 'alpha', location 'A' and 'C' are not connected. Is this due to the order they appear in your data? We need to know how each location is connected to create the appropriate adjacency matrix.

Comment: Nodes of the graph are `Location`s, every `Location` is connected to all other ones, the weight of an edge (possibly zero) is the number of `Customer`s that have visited both places. Kurious, is this interpretation correct?

Comment: In my case, connection between two locations is a common customer who visited them both. For nodes 'A' and 'B', the edge is the count of number of their common customers. This count is 2 because both 'Alpha' and 'Beta' visited them. For 'A' and 'C', the count is 1 because only 'Alpha' visited both of them.

Comment: Yes gboffi, you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach that takes into account the multiplicity of visits (e.g. if Customer X visits both LocA and LocB twice, he will contribute `2` to the corresponding position in the final matrix).

Idea:

1. For each location, count visits by customer.
2. For each location pair, find the sum of minimal numbers of visits for each customer who visited both.
3. Use `unstack` and cleanup.

`Counter` plays nicely here because counters support many natural arithmetic operations, like `add`, `max` etc.

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter
from itertools import product

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Customer_ID': ['Alpha', 'Alpha', 'Alpha', 'Beta', 'Beta'],
    'Location_ID': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B'],
    })


ctrs = {location: Counter(gp.Customer_ID) for location, gp in df.groupby('Location_ID')}


# In [7]: q.ctrs
# Out[7]:
# {'A': Counter({'Alpha': 1, 'Beta': 1}),
#  'B': Counter({'Alpha': 1, 'Beta': 1}),
#  'C': Counter({'Alpha': 1})}


ctrs = list(ctrs.items())
overlaps = [(loc1, loc2, sum(min(ctr1[k], ctr2[k]) for k in ctr1))
    for i, (loc1, ctr1) in enumerate(ctrs, start=1)
    for (loc2, ctr2) in ctrs[i:] if loc1 != loc2]
overlaps += [(l2, l1, c) for l1, l2, c in overlaps]


df2 = pd.DataFrame(overlaps, columns=['Loc1', 'Loc2', 'Count'])
df2 = df2.set_index(['Loc1', 'Loc2'])
df2 = df2.unstack().fillna(0).astype(int)


#      Count
# Loc2     A  B  C
# Loc1
# A        0  2  1
# B        2  0  1
# C        1  1  0
```

If you like to disregard multiplicities, replace `Counter(gp.Customer_ID)` with `Counter(set(gp.Customer_ID))`.

Comment: This is very helpful and comprehensive, thank you. On a side note, can you please give me some tips to think maturely about such problems. I've been programming in Python for close to 2 years now (self-learning). I didn't know about using `Counter` or `product`.

I was messing around with multiple loops.

How do I develop the kind of proficiency that you have demonstrated?

Comment: Now this is a question... I am certainly far from thinking maturely in general, but here are some resources that I've found helpful:
https://projecteuler.net/
https://www.hackerrank.com/
http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/advanced_python/
http://sopython.com/canon/
stackoverflow is obviously great; I like to think that I learn a lot from answering questions like this one.

Comment: There seems to be some issue with the code. I want the matrix to have a 0 if there are no common customers between two locations (like between C-D in the example matrix). However, the present code inputs the count of the customers going to the 'row' location instead.

Comment: Perhaps share an example? I found a bug that could have caused it. Apparently, counter ordering behaved differently from what I thought, so I replaced it with an explicit comprehension.

Comment: I updated the example in the question. Is there additional information I can provide?

Comment: I can reproduce the updated matrix with this version of the code. Let me know if it still has unexpected behavior.

Comment: Follow up question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37257733/creating-a-matrix-from-pandas-dataframe-to-display-connectedness-2

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there's a more elegant way but here's a solution I came up with on the fly. Basically you build an adjacency list for each customer, then update the adjacency matrix accordingly:

```
import pandas as pd

#I'm assuming you can get your data into a pandas data frame:
data = {'Customer_ID':[1,1,1,2,2],'Location':['A','B','C','A','B']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#Initialize an empty matrix
matrix_size = len(df.groupby('Location'))
matrix = [[0 for col in range(matrix_size)] for row in range(matrix_size)]

#To make life easier, I made a map to go from locations 
#to row/col positions in the matrix
location_set = list(set(df['Location'].tolist()))
location_set.sort()
location_map = dict(zip(location_set,range(len(location_set))))

#Group data by customer, and create an adjacency list (dyct) for each
#Update the matrix accordingly
for name,group in df.groupby('Customer_ID'):
    locations = set(group['Location'].tolist())
    dyct = {}
    for i in locations:
        dyct[i] = list(locations.difference(i))

    #Loop through the adjacency list and update matrix
    for node, edges in dyct.items(): 
        for edge in edges:
            matrix[location_map[edge]][location_map[node]] +=1
```

Comment: I get this error:

`TypeError: 'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed` for `matrix = [[0 for col in range(matrix_size)] for row in range(matrix_size)]`

Comment: I removed the unnecessary `set()` from the line `matrix_size = len(set(df.groupby('Location')))`. It works as expected now.