# Creating a matrix from Pandas dataframe to display connectedness - 2

Tags: python, pandas, matrix

This is a follow-up question to [Creating a matrix from Pandas dataframe to display connectedness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37174081/creating-a-matrix-from-pandas-dataframe-to-display-connectedness/37174996#37174996). The difference is in the matrix.

I have my data in this format in a pandas dataframe:

```
Customer_ID  Location_ID
Alpha             A
Alpha             B
Alpha             C
Beta              A
Beta              B
Beta              D
```

I want to study the mobility patterns of the customers. My goal is to determine the clusters of locations that are most frequented by customers. I think the following matrix can provide such information:

```
   A  B  C  D
A  0  0  0  0
B  2  0  0  0
C  1  1  0  0
D  1  1  0  0
```

How do I do so in Python?

My dataset is quite large (hundreds of thousands of customers and about a hundred locations).

Comment: Can you explain why this matrix isn't symmetric? Is it to save space and time?

Comment: Yeah, that's one of the reasons. The other is I visualize it using graph tools, and the two repeats result in duplicate edges when I want my graph to be undirected

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness, here's the modified version of my previous answer. Basically, you add a condition when updating the matrix: `if edge > node:`

```
import pandas as pd

#I'm assuming you can get your data into a pandas data frame:
data = {'Customer_ID':[1,1,1,2,2,2],'Location':['A','B','C','A','B','D']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#Initialize an empty matrix
matrix_size = len(df.groupby('Location'))
matrix = [[0 for col in range(matrix_size)] for row in range(matrix_size)]

#To make life easier, I made a map to go from locations 
#to row/col positions in the matrix
location_set = list(set(df['Location'].tolist()))
location_set.sort()
location_map = dict(zip(location_set,range(len(location_set))))

#Group data by customer, and create an adjacency list (dyct) for each
#Update the matrix accordingly
for name,group in df.groupby('Customer_ID'):
    locations = set(group['Location'].tolist())
    dyct = {}
    for i in locations:
        dyct[i] = list(locations.difference(i))

    #Loop through the adjacency list and update matrix
    for node, edges in dyct.items(): 
        for edge in edges:
            #Add this condition to create bottom half of the symmetric matrix
            if edge > node:
                matrix[location_map[edge]][location_map[node]] +=1
```

Answer (score 0):

The change is 2 characters in this line:

```
overlaps += [(l2, l1, 0) for l1, l2, _ in overlaps]
```

from

```
overlaps += [(l2, l1, c) for l1, l2, c in overlaps]
```

The purpose of this line in the first version was to populate symmetric values. If you want to have a lower diagonal matrix, simply fill the respective keys with zeros.

Original code:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter
from itertools import product

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Customer_ID': ['Alpha', 'Alpha', 'Alpha', 'Beta', 'Beta', 'Beta'],
    'Location_ID': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'D'],
    })


ctrs = {location: Counter(gp.Customer_ID) for location, gp in df.groupby('Location_ID')}


# In [7]: q.ctrs
# Out[7]:
# {'A': Counter({'Alpha': 1, 'Beta': 1}),
#  'B': Counter({'Alpha': 1, 'Beta': 1}),
#  'C': Counter({'Alpha': 1})}


ctrs = list(ctrs.items())
overlaps = [(loc1, loc2, sum(min(ctr1[k], ctr2[k]) for k in ctr1))
    for i, (loc1, ctr1) in enumerate(ctrs, start=1)
    for (loc2, ctr2) in ctrs[i:] if loc1 != loc2]
overlaps += [(l2, l1, 0) for l1, l2, _ in overlaps]


df2 = pd.DataFrame(overlaps, columns=['Loc1', 'Loc2', 'Count'])
df2 = df2.set_index(['Loc1', 'Loc2'])
df2 = df2.unstack().fillna(0).astype(int)


#      Count         
# Loc2     A  B  C  D
# Loc1               
# A        0  0  0  0
# B        2  0  0  0
# C        1  1  0  0
# D        1  1  0  0
```

Comment: I don't get the desired results with this code. The values differ across rows and columns.

Comment: They do. Is it not the desired change from the original question?

Comment: Doesn't look like it. I want all values to be 0 above the diagonal (as is the case in the output you show). Not sure why it isn't working on my data. I will post after I've figured it out